# Correct way to create thread_safe shared_ptr without a lock?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, shared-ptr, atomic

I'm trying to create a class with a thread-safe shared_ptr. My use case is that the shared_ptr belongs to an object of the class, and behaves sort of like a singleton (the CreateIfNotExist function can be run by any thread at any point in time).

Essentially if the pointer is null, the first thread that sets it's value wins, and all other threads that are creating it at the same time use the winning thread's value.

Here is what I have so far (note that the only function in question is the CreateIfNotExist() function, rest is for testing purposes):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

struct A {
    A(int a) : x(a) {}
    int x;
};

struct B {
    B() : test(nullptr) {}

    void CreateIfNotExist(int val) {
        std::shared_ptr<A> newPtr = std::make_shared<A>(val);
        std::shared_ptr<A> _null = nullptr;
        std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&test, &_null, newPtr);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<A> test;
};

int gRet = -1;
std::mutex m;

void Func(B* b, int val) {
    b->CreateIfNotExist(val);
    int ret =  b->test->x;

    if(gRet == -1) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
        if(gRet == -1) {
            gRet = ret;
        }
    }

    if(ret != gRet) {
        std::cout << " FAILED " << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    B b;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        threads.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) threads.emplace_back(&Func, &b, i);
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Is there a better way to ensure that all threads calling CreateIfNotExist() at the same time all use the same shared_ptr?

Comment: Why not make `B` not default contructable so `test` has to be valid?

Comment: Just define a single shared pointer and pass it to each thread as you spawn it?

Comment: @sji I intentionally structured the code in such a way as to fit my use case, it will not be possible without a lot of refactoring to do that

Comment: @Andrew fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
struct B {
  void CreateIfNotExist(int val) {
    std::call_once(test_init,
                   [this, val](){test = std::make_shared<A>(val);});
  }

  std::shared_ptr<A> test;
  std::once_flag test_init;
};
```

Comment: How light-weight is this approach? Would an compare-and-swap be more efficient?

Comment: It depends on your use case. You make the struct bigger for the `once_flag`, but guarantee that only one struct will be created. On the other hand, the approach from the question will not inflate the struct, but can have `n` nearly simultaneous constructions of `A`, only to discard all but one of them. Whichever is better for you is up to you.

Comment: Suppose I also have the requirement that I can set the shared_ptr to nullptr at any point as well, will this approach work?

Comment: What is expected to happen if one thread calls `ResetTestToNull` while the other calls `CreateIfNotExist` at roughly the same time? Are you saying that whoever calls `CreateIfNotExist` can't just go ahead and access `test` afterwards (as your example code is doing), since some other thread could have reset it right after `CreateIfNotExist` call returned? I'm not sure I quite see how one can write anything resembling reliable code under such assumptions.

Comment: You are correct, I should probably refactor the calling code. Thanks.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What if my use case is that I can set it to nullptr, but I can guarantee that it will not happen at the same time as construction? I just need to be able to ensure construction is thread-safe, and can be done multiple times.

Comment: Well, I suppose the function that resets the pointer could also reset the flag - something like this: `test_init.~std::once_flag(); new(&test_init) std::once_flag;`.